# How to remove the decimal numbers from a bar chart in pycharm using python. My code is below

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

label = []
numbers = []

times = int(input("How many labels will you have? "))
print("")


for i in range(times):
    userlabel = input("What is the name of the label? ")
    label.append(userlabel)
    print("")
    numb = int(input("What is the amount of that label? "))
    print("")
    numbers.append(numb)

# plotting
y_pos = np.arange(len(label))
plt.bar(y_pos, numbers, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, label)
# plt.xlabel(labelname)
# plt.title(title)

plt.show()
```

The x axis shows the labels and the y axis the value, for some reason the values also have a decimal point.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to reproduce the plot with decimal point unless I enter floats for `numb`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use just the int values for your y-axis you can add this.

```
# plotting
y_pos = np.arange(len(label))
plt.bar(y_pos, numbers, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, label)

#add
min = 0
max = int(numbers[len(numbers)-1]) + 1
yint=range(min,max)
plt.yticks(yint)

# plt.xlabel(labelname)
# plt.title(title)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to under the xticks:**

```
plt.yticks([n for n in range(int(max(numbers))+1)])
```